# Remote EJB lambda function arguments

Tags: lambda, ejb, java-ee-7

I have stateless EJB which implements @Remote interface like

```
@Remote
interface RemoteEJB{
  <T> void method(DTO<T> dto);
}

public class DTO<T> implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final ToLongFunction<T> fun;
  private final long id;
  
  public DTO(long id, ToLongFunction<T> fun){
     this.id = id;
     // Cast lambda 
     this.fun = (ToLongFunction<T> & Serializable) fun;
  }
  // getters
}
```

I do not understand why **WFLYEJB0054: Failed to marshal EJB parameters Remote EJB** is still thrown even parameters are serializable.

Comment: The `fun` field in `DTO` is not serializable

Comment: So, every field must be serializable? Not only the encapsulation class?